# Docker build step , requires two arguments

Tags: docker

docker build -t project1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 82.77 MB
Step 1/3 : FROM httpd:2.4
---> a8ea074f4566
Step 2/3 : COPY ./usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
COPY requires at least two arguments

Comment: I believe you need to specify the target destination of the content

Comment: so , meanwhile , I created a docs directory and mentioned ./docs as destination in copy command

Comment: COPY ./usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ ./docs
lstat usr/local/apache2/htdocs/: no such file or directory

Comment: @NaphatAmundsen it's saying no such file or dir, but i created a directory with docs

Comment: Are you sure those paths are supposed to be relative? That is, are you sure you want the `.` before the paths in this case?